# Getting error Error: Could not find or load main class in intellij while running a java class, able to run the same through run Configurations

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Getting error Error: Could not find or load main class in intellij while running a java class, able to run the same through run Configurations

[image]
the class highlighted is the one i want to run. Executes well when i am running it through Run configurations.

[image]

Comment: With `javac` your classpath is probably not correctly set. IntelliJ will to that magic using Run configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the `src/main/java` directory and running `javac com/Runners/TestRunnerMutliThreaded.java` from there. Because of the package system, you have to do it this way (which I consider a good thing about java, but I won't have opinions). The package statement at the top of the class is the package of the class (obviously) which basically means if you compile it from another folder, that package might not be correct. If you want more info, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18093929/13173633).